# Karate Authentication only valid for the first request in scenario

Tags: karate

My issue is that I am authorized for the first request (Create article) but not for the 2nd request (getById) although the authorization itself has not changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
Feature: Test Article Endpoint

  Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/v1'
    * header AuthenticationToken = 'sys-test-api-token'


  Scenario: create article, get article ById, update article & delete article
    And request {name: 'TestArtikel', unitName: 'Stk.', articleNumber: '0001'}
    Given path 'article'
    When method post
    Then status 201
    And match response.id == '#notnull'
    
    * def articleId = response.id
    
    Given path 'article/id/:id'    
    And param id = articleId
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For headers that "span" requests, use `configure headers`:

```
* configure headers = { AuthenticationToken: 'sys-test-api-token' }
```

And refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers